# How to make stepper motor run faster

Tags: dc-motor

I'm using a raspberry pi 4 8GB with a DRV8825 driver to run the stepper motor, the stepper motor is a NEMA 17 rated at 1.7 A. The problem is that the stepper motor can't run at high RPM's. I have managed to get the motor to 600 RPM with a delay of 0.00025 (4th argument) between each step (code below). However, when I decrease this value to 0.00015 for example (this is supposed to give 1000 RPM) the motor stalls. How do I stop the motor from stalling. I've tried increasing the current using the potentiometer on the drv8825 driver, nothing happens.

The code that I'm using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from RpiMotorLib import RpiMotorLib
import time


direction_x = 22 # Direction (DIR) GPIO Pin
step_x = 23 # Step GPIO Pin
EN_pin_x = 24 # enable pin (LOW to enable)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(EN_pin_x,GPIO.OUT) # set enable pin as output
GPIO.output(EN_pin_x,GPIO.LOW)# pull enable to low to enable motor

mymotortest_x = RpiMotorLib.A4988Nema(direction_x, step_x, (21,21,21), "DRV8825")


while True:
    mymotortest_x.motor_go(True, "Full", 100000000, 0.00025, False, 0.0005)
```

1st argument - boolean value, controls the clockwise (False) or counterclockwise (True) motion of the rotation 2nd argument - controls the stepping increment based on the DRV8825 MS1-MS3 values. The 0-1 value of each of the MS1-MS3 values controls the stepping increment following the specification in the table below:[image: MS1-MS3]

So for my code (full step) the ms1 - ms3 values should be set to 0. 3rd argument - controls the number of steps to take. 4th argument - controls the delay between each step. 5th argument - controls the printout of debugging information of the RpiMotorLib. 6th argument - the initial delay before the motor control begins.

For further information the article for the wiring and further detail is [here](https://makersportal.com/blog/raspberry-pi-stepper-motor-control-with-nema-17).

Comment: please put all information into your question ... a question here should stand on its own, without the need to follow links

Comment: What sort of RPM are you getting?  What sort of RPM do you want?  Are you microstepping?  Have you tried just sending the pulses directly?

Comment: I'm getting around 200 RPM and I want ~700 RPM or higher. In the code above I'm doing a full step so there is no microstepping, I've tried microstepping but that is slower than doing a full step since there are more steps and there's more pauses between each step

Comment: That information should be in your question.  700RPM needs 700*200/60 or 2333 pulses per second.  Well within the capabilities of the Pi.

Comment: Welcome, Ramin, but your latest edit seems to incorporate details provided in the existing answer, ie., you've applied the answer and then changed the question to reflect the result.   This effectively invalidates the answer, because the question is now different.  This might be okay in a running dialog forum, but it is not how things work here; we have a fairly strict format that new users accustomed to "discussion style" forums sometimes find awkward.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: If you wish to continue with this here, you should "rollback" the edit (click the "edited X hours ago" link) to what it was before the answer was posted, then cut and paste the new version into a new question.

Comment: Did you accelerate slowly, or did you jump directly to the high speed?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code and python library description, the most relevant parameters should be stepping increment, delay between steps and the initial delay. The example in the article you have shared uses `Full` (i.e. 200 steps per revolution) for the increment and `0.0005` for the step delay. Recalculating 200 steps/revolution * 0.0005 seconds, we end up with 600 RPM. In addition to that the manual suggests that:

> The fourth argument, a float value, controls the delay between each step. This is perhaps the most sensitive parameter in the call to motor_go(), as different current settings and motors can cause different behavior based on this value. If the motor is experiencing some jittering, this value may need to be decreased.

Which may means that with `0.0003` second step delays you are using may not be suitable for your motor. Based on that the following can be tried to increase the speed:

- Start with longer step delay(e.g. 0.005), lower number of steps (e.g. 2000) in an infinite loop as you do it and with current sett according to motor datasheet. Check RPM, see if you get 60 as expected. Observe the motor behavior see if it is able to rotate continuously and if adjusting step number is required.
- Iteratively decrease step delay to the value that would correspond to 700 RPM (~0.00042) e.g. setting 0.0025, 0.0001, 0.00075, 0.0005, 0.00042. Check the speed and observe motor behavior, see at which moment decreasing delay will not increase RPM as expected or will start do deviate significantly from an expected value.
- Once the delay is set, consider changing number of steps and see what will be the effect.
- Pay attention to another delay parameter - initial delay (6th argument). If you want to run motor continuously and evenly, this may need to match the step delay or to be set to 0. it is not very clear from the description, you may want to experiment with it.

*The exact way calculating RPM based on step delay `d` and increment `t` is:* `60/t/d`, e.g. 1/(200 steps/revolution) / (0.0005 sec/step) * 60 sec / minute = 600 revolution/minute (RPM)

Final note: if you aim at high rotation speeds in combination with continuous rotation, stepper motor might not be the best choice. They are designed for precise and rather discrete motion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I set the values to the values stated in the first bullet point (with initial delay set to 0), I get 30 RPM, half the expected amount. And does the equation "200 steps/revolution * 0.0005 seconds" equal to the RPM? If it does the what does "revolution" mean in the equation

Comment: I managed to get the motor to 60 RPM by halving the delay, and then to 600 RPM by using a tenth of the delay. But now I realise I need it to be faster but when I decrease the delay to 0.00015 the motor starts to stall (this value should give 1000 RPM) how do i stop the motor from stalling?

Comment: I've added a formula to do RPM calculation to the answer. With regards to getting beyond 600 RPM, try going stepwise, decreasing step delay by 10-20% every time. Once you see that it slows down try playing with current (both increase or decrease). Though, my feeling is that you won't get much faster. As said above steppers are designed for precise discrete motion. Here my assumption is that you are hitting physical limits of the motor itself.